# pytorch: Only divide values greater than certain value

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to divide one tensor by another in torch, but only when the values of the denominator exceed a certain threshold.

This implementation works, but won't compile in torchdynamo.

```py
wsq_ola = wsq_ola.to(wav).expand_as(wav).clone()
min_mask = wsq_ola.abs() < eps
wav[~min_mask] = wav[~min_mask] / wsq_ola[~min_mask]
```

I tried to implement the same thing with `torch.where` instead as follows:

```py
wsq_ola = wsq_ola.to(wav).expand_as(wav).clone()
min_mask = wsq_ola.abs() < eps
wav = torch.where(min_mask, wav, wav / wsq_ola)
```

Unfortunately, once I make this change, the model no longer converges. Is there some issue with my use of torch.where here? For context, this is part of an stft layer with no trainable weights.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is relevant, but do `wav` and `wsq_ola` happen to have different dtypes? `torch.where` participates in type promotion so, e.g., if `wav` is float32 and `wsq_ola` is float64, the result in the `torch.where` implementation would convert `wav` to double. Your first implementation is in-place and wouldn't result in a change in dtypes for the same inputs.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the issue. it's all the same dtype

Comment: another thought: If you were using pytorch prior to version 1.2, `<` would return uint8's instead of bools, and `~ torch.tensor([1, 0], dtype=uint8)` gives `[254, 255]` not `0,1`.

Comment: also I think in-place operations can sometimes affect gradient tracking, but that would affect the first not second example, and I believe would lead to an error if it was relevant.